# index.js ban command available to all users

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my code for kick/ban command
I am using an advanced command handler
how do i set the permission to a specific role.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`You couldn't kick that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if the `author` of the message have the given role. For this you will have to know the ID of the given role.

```js
const roleID = '...some role ID...';
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(roleID)) {
            // Not authorized
            return;
        }
        
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`You couldn't kick that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```